Is there a way to disable system status notices for all users?
Is there a way to disable the system status notice popup that appears at the top right in civiCRM when extensions need updating, etc?

Yes, in your system status page you have the option to mute any notification.

It comes from https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/f4c1e3dda512da22796fc821e264a7359d5a3fcd/CRM/Utils/Check.php#L82 so you have a couple options:

Remove administer CiviCRM system permission from the users. (Note administer CiviCRM also includes that permission.)
Use https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_check to adjust the severity of the messages or hide them. This will also affect how they appear when manually visiting the status page.
Hack the above function.


Wouldn't it also work to mute the message?

Yes until the next one comes up. I understood the question to be asking about all future ones too, from all checks.
